# i can't send email using javamail

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

i'm using javamail, i've tried using authentication, or without, but it doesn't work.
is there someone who can help?

```
 private boolean InitMailer(String sSMPTGateWay)
{
    try
    {
        oProps=new Properties();
        oProps.put("mail.smtp.host",sSMPTGateWay);
        //oProps.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        //oProps.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
        oProps.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

      //  oProps.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
    //      "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    oProps.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    //oProps.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

        Authenticator auth = new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication("mmyemail@gmail.com","mypassword");
            }
        };

        oSession=Session.getInstance(oProps,auth);
        oSession.setDebug(true);
        oTransport=oSession.getTransport(oSession.getProvider("smtp"));
        System.out.println("tento di connettermi");
        oTransport.connect();
        System.out.println("connesso?");
        if(!oTransport.isConnected())
        {
            ErrorLog.warningLog("MService: MService(): Mail Server "+sMailGateWay+" non operativo. Tento un altro Gateway.");
            return false;
        }
   }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        ErrorLog.warningLog("MService: MService(): Mail Server "+sMailGateWay+" non operativo. Tento un altro Gateway.");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private void sendMessage(String sFrom,String sTo,String sSubject,String sBody) throws Exception
{
        if(Constants.ENABLE_MAIL_SERVICE.equals("NO"))
        {
            ErrorLog.warningLog("Tentativo di invio, Mail disabilitata: \n From:"+sFrom+"\n To:"+ sTo +"\n Subject: "+sSubject + "\n Body:\n"+sBody);
            return;
        }
        if(Constants.ENABLE_MAIL_SERVICE.equals("TEST"))
            sTo=Constants.TEST_MAIL;

        MimeMessage msg=new MimeMessage(oSession);
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(sFrom));
        msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(sTo));
        msg.setSubject(sSubject,"iso-8859-1");
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());
        msg.setText(sBody,"iso-8859-1");
        System.out.println("mando mex");
        oTransport.send(msg);
}
```

and this is the error, well it's not an error but the email isn't sent

```
220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP q4sm9246160wjk.24 - gsmtp
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "smtp.gmail.com", port: 25

EHLO Michele
250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [79.36.174.226]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250 SMTPUTF8
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "35882577"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SMTPUTF8", arg ""
connesso?
NOOP
250 2.0.0 OK q4sm9246160wjk.24 - gsmtp
new MSERVICE
starcinema@gmail.com
Sending from (starcinemafe@gmail.com) to (starcinema@gmail.com) subject (Registrazione Star Cinema) html(false).
mando mex1
mando mex
NOOP
250 2.0.0 OK q4sm9246160wjk.24 - gsmtp
```

Answer (score 1):

Fix all these [common JavaMail mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes) and you'll get further.  In particular, call oTransport.sendMessage instead of oTransport.send.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes happen when you're using a local smtp server is that your ISP will block port `25`

If you are using the SMTP server provided by the host provider  you need to authenticate the username and password. The javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication class is used to authenticate the password.

Try changing `properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");`

to `properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");`// `465 also option`

check if you are not getting any solution [Java mail mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes)

Answer (score 0):

The error you post is about Properties. Change for it.

```
    oProps.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    oProps.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    oProps.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    oProps.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.gmail.com");
    oProps.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
```